# Default Value for Join Predicate as Method Parameter

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have a method that selects data.  It can support multiple use cases if the caller can provide a predicate to modify the `.Where()`.  I attempted something like

```
private class ABJoin
{
    public A A { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
}

bool NoFilter(ABJoin join, int index)
{
    return true; // Don't filter at all for this
}

private IEnumerable<TResult> GetData
(Func<ABJoin, int, bool> filter)
{
    var query = ctx.TypeA
        .Join(ctx.TypeB, a => a.BId, b => b.Id, 
              (a, b) => new ABJoin() { A = a, B = b })
    // etc.
}
```

Works great, so far.

However, some use cases do not need to provide any filter (the real version has other parameters to distinguish behavior per use case).  I thought it would be handy to provide a default value for the filter parameter

```
private IEnumerable<TResult> GetData
(Func<ABJoin, int, bool> filter = NoFilter)
```

However, that does not compile.  The error states that `NoFilter` must be a compile-time constant.

Is there a way to provide a default value for `filter` in `GetData()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide default value of `null` and swap it with real delegate inside the method:

```
private IEnumerable<TResult> GetData(Func<ABJoin, int, bool> filter = null)
{
    filter = filter ?? ((a,b) => true);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't compile for me.  I'm using C# 5 if it makes a difference.  Says `a does not exist in the current context`.